# Generating multiple columns from a dynamically generated list in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, multiple-columns, megamenu

I have a script that generates the UL LI statements, and creates a single column list, now I need to modify that so instead of a long list, I divide it in several columns, each with 10 elements until the end.

```
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($manufacturer_sidebox_array);$i++) {

  $content = '';
  $content .= '<li ><a class="hide" href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT,   'manufacturers_id=' . $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['id']) . '">';
  $content .= $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['text'];
  $content .= '</a></li>' . "\n";
  echo $content;
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to insert some if statements in a way I can create the columns.

Right now the output is:

Col1

first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
.
.
.
twentieth

What I want is:

Col1                 Col2          Col3     ... Col6

first                11th          21th         nth
.
.
.
10th                 20th          30th

Comment: And you want these columns stacked next to each other vertically, and all part of the same HTML list?

Comment: Hey there. I posted an answer for you below. Check it out, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This will break the array into groups of ten, wrapping each group in a `column` div. Notice that we begin the first div before the loop and end the last div after the loop. The crucial piece to break at 10 entries is the modulus operator - `%` - you can read about it [in the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
echo '<div class="menuColumn">';

for ($i=0; $i<count($manufacturer_sidebox_array); $i++) {

    if ($i % 10 == 0){
        echo '</div><div class="menuColumn">';
    }

    $content = '';
    $content .= '<li ><a class="hide" href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT,   'manufacturers_id=' . $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['id']) . '">';
    $content .= $manufacturer_sidebox_array[$i]['text'];
    $content .= '</a></li>' . "\n";
    echo $content;

}

echo '</div>';
```

You'll also need this CSS style to make the columns stack next to each other horizontally instead of the default vertical stacking. Obviously you can adjust the margin to suit your preferences:

```
<style>
.menuColumn{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that and let you know, I already have column classes  but yours is much better .. ;)

Comment: ok, I 've tried your solution and it worked ... partially because it messed up the whole site do you want me to post the whole css file and the php code, so you can take a look? It seems your additional div messed up the current divs.

Comment: If you already had a column class, I would just change my new one to `echo '</div><div class="menuColumn">';` and the CSS to `.menuColumn{` and leave your other styles intact. Is that what you did, or did you make a hybrid somehow?

Comment: @RickFitzgerald Ok, good to hear. If you could accept my answer, that would be great.